# Label text background color in Maui

Tags: background, maui

How can I achieve such an effect with an Label in maui. It looks somehow like selected text and I couldn't find something similar in the API.

[background label text in .net maui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJOth.png)

This is not a background color for the view, but a background color only for the text. You can see how it stops at line breaks and has a thin white line between text lines.

Comment: You can use `Span` to format Label. But it can't have a thin white line between text lines. Here is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EwfP.png).

Comment: Would TextDecorations Underline work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As FreakyAli said that you can use `TextDecorations` to close to that effect (have a thin white line between text lines) :

```xml
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString >
            <Span TextColor="White"
                  BackgroundColor="SkyBlue"
                  TextDecorations="Underline"
                  Text="A Span can also respond to any gestures that are added to the span's GestureRecognizers collection. For example, a TapGestureRecognizer has been added to the second Span in the above examples."/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

And here is the effect:

[image]